# Cómo excluir una carpeta del archivo .gitignore en laravel

Tags: laravel, git

tengo la siguiente subcarpeta en mi storage

```
storage
     ->app
          ->SalesforceKeys
```

el problema es que dentro de la carpeta `app` tengo un archivo .gitignore el cual no me deja incluir la carpeta `SalesforceKeys` en el commit, intenté editarlo para que la incluya pero creo que no hizo efecto

**storage\app.gitignore:**

```
*
!public/
!SalesforceKeys/
!.gitignore
```

no sé si estará bien de esa forma, ¿o tengo que hacer algo más?

además
dentro de la carpeta `SalesforceKeys` tengo archivos de texto `.key` que incluyen keys bastante largas que no estoy poniendo en el .env porque son muy largas y tienen saltos de línea, así que me recomendaron ponerlas en los archivos .key y obtenerlas mediante el storage, por ejemplo

```
Storage::disk('local')->get('SalesforceKeys/area_check.key');
```

me surge una duda, no habrán problemas de seguridad por hacerlo de esta manera? es decir, públicamente no se podrá tener acceso a la key?

gracias por su tiempo :)

Comment: ¿Son claves privadas lo que tienes en esos archivos?

Comment: storage no puede subir al repositorio

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ sí, son claves privadas

Comment: Entonces te sugiero que no las agregues a git, pues sería información sensible. Así como se ignora para git el archivo `.env`, pues allí va información sensible (como usuario y contraseña de la BD), tampoco deberías agregar ninguna otra info sensible a un repositorio. En todo caso, cuando hagas un deploy de tu aplicación, subes aparte esos archivos